# Mailing Service

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am doing a project using Codeigniter (Mobile Website). I want users to receive mails such as registration, forgot password, newsletters etc. Currently what I am doing is like :

```
function sendEmail($email) {
        $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => '465',
            'smtp_user' => 'user@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
            );
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('user@gmail.com', 'user');
        $this->email->to($email);
        $this->email->subject('Thank You for Registering');
        $this->email->message('Thank You for Registering .');
        if($this->email->send()){
            echo "Success";
        }
        else {
            echo "failed";
        }
    }
```

This works well. But is this the right way of doing things when you want to send mails of 2-3 types ? Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not using Gmail smtp for a web application in production. Instead use premium (paid) services like  [www.mailgin.com](http://www.mailgin.com) where you can also use your own domain for sending, etc. 
Or set up your own email server.

I would also recommend using a framework for sending the emails, for example [www.swiftmailer.org](http://www.swiftmailer.org)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create `email.php` file in `./application/config` folder and put your config array in that file. So when you change your email settings it will reflect in entire application. For more details visit [Email class in codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html).